# R: How to sum values from rows only if the key value is the same and also if the key duplicated in consecutive rows?

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following data table of this structure:

```
+-------------------+
| id  | key | value |
+-----+-----+-------+
| 1   | A   | 1000  |
| 1   | A   | 2000  |
| 1   | B   | 2001  |
| 1   | A   | 2002  |
| 1   | A   | 2004  |
| 2   | B   | 2002  |
| 2   | C   | 2002  |
+-------------------+
```

My objective is to sum the values by id and key but instead of just grouping by id and key, I only want to sum the values if the pair of id and key are the same for consecutive rows.

The result should be:

```
+-------------------+
| id  | key | value |
+-----+-----+-------+
| 1   | A   | 3000  |
| 1   | B   | 2001  |
| 1   | A   | 4006  |
| 2   | B   | 2002  |
| 2   | C   | 2002  |
+-------------------+
```

Is there anyway to achieve this result?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can use `rleid` from `data.table`.

We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table'.  Create another grouping column 'ind' from the 'key' column.  Grouped by 'id' and 'ind', we get the `sum` of 'value' and get the first element of 'key'.  We can assign the 'ind' to NULL as it is not needed in the expected output.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[,list(value = sum(value), key=key[1L]),
                    by = .(ind=rleid(key), id)][, ind:=NULL][]
#   id value key
#1:  1  3000   A
#2:  1  2001   B
#3:  1  4006   A
#4:  2  2002   B
#5:  2  2002   C
```

Or as @Frank suggested, we can use mutliple columns within `rleid`, use it as grouping variable, get the first element of other variables and `sum` of 'value',  assign the unwanted column to `NULL` to avoid copies.

```
setDT(df1)[, list(id=id[1L], key=key[1L], value=sum(value)) ,
        by = .(r=rleid(id, key))][, r:= NULL][]
#   id key value
#1:  1   A  3000
#2:  1   B  2001
#3:  1   A  4006
#4:  2   B  2002
#5:  2   C  2002
```

---

Or we can use `dplyr`.  We create the grouping variable 'ind' by comparing the adjacent elements of 'key', and get the `sum` of 'value' and the `first` element of 'key' with `summarise`.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
     group_by(ind= cumsum(key!=lag(key, default=TRUE)), id) %>%
     summarise(value=sum(value), key=first(key)) %>% 
     ungroup() %>%
     select(-ind)
#  id value key
#1  1  3000   A
#2  1  2001   B
#3  1  4006   A
#4  2  2002   B
#5  2  2002   C
```

NOTE: In the `dplyr` and `data.table` we can also place the 'key' column as the grouping variable and remove the `key=key[1L]` or `key=first(key))`.

---

Or we `transform` the dataset by creating the 'ind' column and use `aggregate` from `base R` to get the expected output

```
df1 <- transform(df1, ind = cumsum(c(TRUE,head(key,-1)!=tail(key,-1))))
aggregate(value~., df1, FUN=sum)[-3]
#  id key value
#1  1   A  3000
#2  1   B  2001
#3  1   A  4006
#4  2   B  2002
#5  2   C  2002
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), key = c("A", 
"A", "B", "A", "A", "B", "C"), value = c(1000L, 2000L, 2001L, 
2002L, 2004L, 2002L, 2002L)), .Names = c("id", "key", "value"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Comment: You seem to be relying on sorting by `id`..? For what it's worth, `rleid` can take two arguments, getting around this concern: `DT[, .(id=id[1],key=key[1],value=sum(value)), by=.(r=rleid(id,key))][,!"r",with=FALSE]`

Comment: @Frank Thanks.  I haven't benchmarked it, hopefully your method would be efficient.

Comment: (Not very important:) I wasn't thinking about efficiency, just logical coherence -- translating "if the pair of id and key are the same for consecutive rows" into code. I'm not sure whether it should be more efficient.